# Bug with ListVectorPlot in 12.3.1?

Tags: plotting, bugs, vector

**Bug fixed in 13.0.0**

---

The documentation shows that result of

```
data = Table[{{x, y} = RandomReal[{-3, 3}, {2}], {y, -x}}, {200}];
ListVectorPlot[data, VectorPoints -> All]
```

should be

[image]

but I get

[image]

i.e., it appears VectorPoints isn't doing anything?  Is this a known bug?

For now, I'm just going to roll my own.

Comment: Fixed in 13.0.0

Comment: I reproduce the problem with version 12.3.1, but not with 13.0.0 on Windows 10 x64. So the bug is fixed in 13.0.0.